# proximity alert does not fire and notify

Tags: android, location, alert, proximity, alerts

Does anyone know what is the issue that cause fire alert not working when get into the proximity radius? I has been struggled for a week in solving this issue and I will really appreciated if anyone can help me out on this issue or give me some guide to complete it.

MainActivity.java

```
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final long POINT_RADIUS = 150; // in Meters
    private static final long PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION = -1; // will not expire
    private static final String PROX_ALERT_INTENT = "com.example.myalert";
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    double latitude = 2.81202, longitude = 101.75989;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
        PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intent, 0);
        locationManager.addProximityAlert(latitude, longitude, POINT_RADIUS, PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, proximityIntent); 
    }

}
```

ProximityReceiver.java

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class ProximityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
       Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);
       if (entering) {
                  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering");
           }else {
                  Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
           }
           NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

           Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
           PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationIntent, 0);
           Notification notification = createNotification();
           notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, "Proximity Alert!", "You are near your point of interest.", pendingIntent);

           notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
    }

    private Notification createNotification() {
        Notification notification = new Notification();
        notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
        notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
        notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
        notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
        notification.ledOnMS = 1500;
        notification.ledOffMS = 1500;
        return notification;
  }
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myalert"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.myalert.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
             android:name="ProximityReceiver">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have not set the receiver in the manifest, "ProximityReceiver" is not an Activity but a receiver.
Try something like this.

```
 <receiver android:name="ProximityReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.example.myalert" />
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Cheers.